# Should you include unknown/default value in java enums

Tags: java, coding-style, enums

For best practices, is it better to have the code as it is below with the `return "red"` to simulate an unknown value? Or should I add an `unknown("red")` option and do `return Shape.unknown.color;` ? Is there a standard Java convention for enums about unknown values?

```
private enum Shape {
    triangle("yellow"),
    square("green"),
    circle("red");

    private final String color;
    Shape(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }
};

public String getShapeColor() {
    if(shape != null) {
        return shape.color;
    }
    return "red";
}
```

Comment: How could you have an unknown value?  In other words, how could it get to the `return "red";` line?

Comment: @DanielKaplan, `shape` is being passed in from another service, so it could be null. and the color's will be used as part of a display on a web page, so we want to have a default value instead of 500'ing

Comment: Oh I see, I read your example wrong.  I thought `getShapeColor()` was inside the enum.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An enum is implicitly a kind of variable which is not supposed to have an uninitialized value.

Actually your reasoning is true for every kind of variable, not just enums, but in the specific case of enums you declare a type which can have a finite number of possible values so `null` shouldn't be an option.

Best solution is indeed to have an unknown value:

```
private enum Shape {
    TRIANGLE("yellow"),
    SQUARE("green"),
    CIRCLE("red"),

    UNKNOWN("unknown");

    private final String color;
    Shape(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }
};
```

And initialize every variable of `Shape` type to `Shape.UNKNOWN` just to avoid doing any null check, which is a sort of [null design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern). This pattern makes even more sense when working with enums.

A note: since enums represent constants, conventions are to give them uppercase names with underscore.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, a shape variable will be null if it's unknown, so I would opt for a static method that you pass your instance into

```
public static String getShapeColor(Shape shape) {
    if(shape != null) {
        return shape.color;
    }
    return "red";
}
```